# Scale group of images to fit parent width/height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with a variously-sized images in it, which is inside of a parent container.

```
<div id="parentContainer">
<div id="boxToScale">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x350" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x200" />
</div>
</div>
```

I need to scale `#boxToScale` so that it fits inside `#parentContainer` (both width and height-wise), while all of the images inside of it keep their aspect ratios. All of the images should be scaled at the same factor, and remain on the same line.

Here's a jsfiddle showing the setup: http://jsfiddle.net/32sm4/

I've found lots of stuff for scaling a single image proportionally, but not for scaling a group of images proportionally. I don't know beforehand what the size of the images will be, only the size of `#parentContainer`.

Javascript/jquery solutions are fine if it can't be done with just css. Thanks!

Edit: Here's (roughly) what I want it to look like after `#boxToScale` has been scaled:
[image]

Comment: is this what you are after? http://jsfiddle.net/7dpHK/2/ Not sure about other layout parameters like setting tops to center images vertically.

Comment: @charlietfl "All of the images should be scaled at the same factor, and remain on the same line." That does not do that. All images should be resized by height & width.

Comment: need more explicit definition of scaling you want. They stay on same line for me in FF and not 100% clear what your expectations are. None can be taller than others? Aspect ratio is being maintained currently as far as I see

Comment: good way to display what you want is manually set image dimensions/posiitons to show output you expect or provide an image of layout expected

Comment: @charlietfl I've added a picture showing what I want. You're correct though, I should have been more explicit in my definition of the expected layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated my answer after I saw your picture how you would your pictures be like.

This is based on this [jsfiddle.net/7dpHK/2](http://jsfiddle.net/7dpHK/2) (**charlietfl** commented this on your question). It's almost working like you wanted, but it was bugging because of those 4px borders/paddings around images. There was some confusing CSS too.
So you have to calculate your borders like:

```
var border = $("#boxToScale img").length * 4;
```

And then just subtract it from `parentW`:

```
parentW = $box.width() - border
```

**[Working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/7dpHK/4/)**

JS:

```
var border = $("#boxToScale img").length * 4; // 4px padding around every image
var $box = $('#boxToScale'),
    parentW = $box.width() - border,
    parentH = $box.height(),
    imageTotalW = 0,
    imageTotalH = 0,
    $imgs = $box.children();

$imgs.each(function () {
    var img = $(this),
        ht = img.height(),
        w = img.outerWidth()

    imageTotalW += w;
    img.data('w', w);

});

var img_width_ratio = parentW / imageTotalW;
$imgs.each(function (idx) {
    var $this = $(this),
        $prev = $this.prev();
    $this.width($this.outerWidth() * img_width_ratio);
});
```

<s>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PH7Bt/)**</s>

JS:

```
function calculateAspectRatioFit(srcWidth, srcHeight, maxWidth, maxHeight) {
    var ratio = [maxWidth / srcWidth, maxHeight / srcHeight ];
    ratio = Math.min(ratio[0], ratio[1]);

    return { width:srcWidth*ratio, height:srcHeight*ratio };
}

imagesInContainer = $("#boxToScale img").length;

var toWidth = $("#parentContainer").width() / imagesInContainer;
var toHeight = $("#parentContainer").height() / imagesInContainer;

$("#boxToScale img").each(function(){
    var imageWidth = $(this).width();
    var imageHeight = $(this).height();
    var getRatio = calculateAspectRatioFit(imageWidth, imageHeight, toWidth, toHeight);
    $(this).width(getRatio.width);
    $(this).height(getRatio.height);
});
```

**Note**: Your 1px border in images may bug this code. See an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PH7Bt/1/) without borders.

Comment: just friendly FYI - if want total number of elements can use `$('selector').length` without needing to create an `each` loop

Comment: Actually: It looks like ( http://jsfiddle.net/tU6yS/1/ ) the images aren't scaled at the same factor. In that link, the first image is scaled twice as small as the second one. I would like them to be all scaled at the same factor. (So the 2000x2000 image will still be twice as big as the 1000x1000 image after they've been scaled.)

Comment: @penguinrob Yea, I understood your question wrong first time. See updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
#boxToScale {
border: solid blue 1px;
white-space: nowrap;
}

#boxToScale img {
 width:20%;
 height:auto;
 display:inline-block;
 }
```

crazy.. but might work...  hope it helps.

Comment: `might work` is hardly an answer .... and in this case it definitely won't. Should prove your solution with a demo